# layer.addData - circle marker style pointToLayer

Tags: leaflet, geojson

So, my problem resides when creating a layer. then adding data to it later. but the style feature not taking control. and it adding default style.

Here is some code that I have. That creates a layer. Then adds data to that layer. But my problem is once the layer has been created and added. The layer won't render any new points with the style.

Is there a style option for the add data function?

```
let tlll = []; let map = this.map; let lc = this.lcontrol; let tll = null;
let ml = mapdata.layers; let a = null; let b = null; let c = null;
let smf = this.styleFeature;
   Object.keys(ml).forEach(function(k){
        tll =  L.geoJson().addTo(map, {pointToLayer:smf});
        a = k;
        Object.keys(ml[k]).forEach(function(v){
             console.log(v);
             b = v;
             Object.keys(ml[k][v]).forEach(function(vv){
                  tll.addData({
                       type: 'Point',
                       coordinates: [ml[k][v][vv].lng,ml[k][v][vv].lat],
                       properties: ml[k][v][vv]
                  });
        });
   });
   c = lc.addOverlay(tll,b,a);
   tlll.push(c);
});
this.testloclayer = tlll;
this.map.setView(tll.getBounds().getCenter());
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem was in this part of the code.

```
tll =  L.geoJson().addTo(map, {pointToLayer:smf});
```

should be

```
tll =  L.geoJson(null, {pointToLayer:smf}).addTo(map);
```